# How to fill `std::vector<std::vector<T> >` with default values?

Tags: c++, stl, vector, std

So I try this:

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > matrix(4);

matrix[0][0] = 1;
matrix[0][1] = 2;
matrix[0][2] = 3;
matrix[0][3] = 1;

matrix[1][0] = 1;
matrix[1][1] = 2;
matrix[1][2] = 3;
matrix[1][3] = 1;

matrix[2][0] = 1;
matrix[2][1] = 2;
matrix[2][2] = 3;
matrix[2][3] = 1;

matrix[3][0] = 1;
matrix[3][1] = 2;
matrix[3][2] = 3;
matrix[3][3] = 1;
```

But something goes wrong and my app dies at runtime=( What to do? How to embed values into vector of vectors correctly?

Comment: Besides that you don't resize your vectors, can you use c++11?

Comment: nope, sadly no C++11 for me=(

Comment: But I do wonder about how this can be done diferently in C++11?

Comment: You might want to provide a class that simulates the matrix with a single allocation of 4x4 elements and `operator()(int,int)` to access each element. That is a common pattern to provide an N-dimensional array (single allocator, accessor that takes N indices and performs the arithmetic internally)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: And if you really want the `[x][y]`-syntax, you can that class's `operator[]` return a proxy class `MatrixRow` or something.

Comment: @user1040114: c++11 can use the unifid initializer syntax of something like `{{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8}}` ... you might also be able to use boost assign here in c++03

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this:

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > matrix(4, std::vector<int>(4));
```

This initializes your outer vector with 4 copies of `std::vector<int>(4)`.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you can take Björn's approach one step farther and fully initialize the 2D vector as you outlined with the values you supplied:

```
std::vector<int> tmp(4,0); 
tmp[0] = 1;
tmp[1] = 2;
tmp[2] = 3;
tmp[3] = 1;

std::vector< std::vector<int> > matrix(4, tmp);
```

One could simply have written it as:

```
std::vector<int> tmp(4,1); 
tmp[1] = 2;
tmp[2] = 3;

std::vector< std::vector<int> > matrix(4, tmp);
```

but I often favor the first for clarity.

Comment: +1: You can make that even better by using [`Boost.Assign`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/assign/doc/index.html#list_of).

Comment: @Björn …or you can reference my example, as I did yours ;)